# Querying Suppression List

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql, suppressionlist

We're making some use of suppression lists and I'm finding that although they seem to live in _ListSubscribers I'm not getting query results when writing SQL to query their ID or Name. Attached is a couple sample queries. What am I missing?

```
SELECT * FROM _listsubscribers
WHERE 1=1 
AND ListID = '[1111111]'
```

and...

```
SELECT * FROM _listsubscribers
WHERE 1=1 
AND ListName = 'My great suppression list'
```

Data Extension is a carbon copy of _listsubscribers and is formatted as follows:

```
AddedBy / Number
AddMethod / Text / 17
CreatedDate / Date (Nullable)
DateUnsubscribed / Date (Nullable)
ListID / Number (Nullable)
ListName / Text / 50 (Nullable)
ListType / Text / 16 (Nullable)
Status / Text / 12 (Nullable)
SubscriberID / Number (Nullable)
SubscriberKey / Text / 254 
SubscriberType / Text / 100 (Nullable)
```

I've also read the documentation and they recommend a slightly different query and DE, listed below, still no results.

Query:

```
SELECT
SubscriberKey,
EmailAddress,
ListName,
ListType,
Status,
CreatedDate AS DateAdded,
DateUnsubscribed
FROM _ListSubscribers
WHERE 1=1 
AND ListName = 'My great suppression list'
```

Data Extension:

```
SubscriberKey / Text / 255 (Key)
EmailAddress / EmailAddress / 254
ListName / Text / 100
ListType / Text / 50 (Nullable)
Status / Text / 25
DateAdded / Date
DateUnsubscribed / Date (Nullable)
```

Comment: Why are you using where `1=1`

Comment: 1=1 is a basic SQL include so that any statement after can start with an AND or OR statement. Just personal preference, and has no impact on other queries.

Answer (score 3):

The ListID field in the [ListSubscribers system data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5) is an integer.  I would recommend changing the syntax in your where clause from *'[1111111]'* to *1111111*.  Also, I would recommend not using the wildcard in you select statement, but specifically call out the column you want to select.

**Example:**

```
SELECT AddedBy, AddMethod, CreatedDate, DateUnsubscribed
 , EmailAddress, ListID, ListName, ListType
 , Status, SubscriberID, SubscriberKey, SubscriberType 
FROM _listsubscribers
WHERE ListID = 1111111
```

Comment: question: can you confirm your query is completing successfully?  I would recommend running in an automation to do this.